# Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome trying to run Rescuetime on NixOS

Tags: wayland, nixos, xcb

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

Y tried

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland rescuetime
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb rescuetime
```

But I have the same output

How can I make this work? thanks!